# Pass parameters to view

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-views

I'm try pass some parameters to view constructor.

I'm creating my object in this way: `new HeadCell({isSortable: true, parent: this});`

So in the HeadCell initialize:

```
initialize: function(options){
   console.log("HeadCell initialized");
   console.log(options);
   console.log(options.isSortable);
}
```

The console output is:

> HeadCell initialized
> Object {isSortable: true, parent: r}
>
> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'isSortable' of undefined

Any ideas?

**UPDATE 1**

Im try run a little test in a fiddle, and the result is the same.

http://jsfiddle.net/ramiromd90/hHFP3/

**UPDATE 2**

I try your examples on fiddle, and works fine ! But, in my code not works.

Here a fiddle with a little example of my real code:

http://jsfiddle.net/ramiromd90/XCK47/

**UPDATE 3**

Thanks for all replies, the problem was that i dont pass the parameters in the loop (see the fiddle). The ways to pass parameters that us says are correct !. Thanks

Comment: Works fine (http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/3HTq2/), can you provide a demo of your problem?

Comment: @muistooshort i update the thread with a fiddle example.

Comment: You have `initialize: function() {` in your fiddle but `initialize: function(options) {` in your question, the latter works fine (http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/bcU57/). Views don't set `this.options` automatically anymore, that was removed in version 1.1: http://backbonejs.org/#changelog

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code in your fiddle is incorrect because you're calling `this.options` when the options parameter is never initialized as part of the view object. In other words, **you're calling a property that doesn't exist**.

Try this instead:

```
$(function(){
    var Aview = Backbone.View.extend({
        initialize: function(options){
            console.log(options.foo);
            console.log(options.bar);
        }
    });

    new Aview({foo:'isFoo!',bar:'isBar!'}); 
});
```

Now, lets get into a bit more detail on what's actually happening to the options parameter when you pass it as an argument to the constructor.

According to the [doc](http://backbonejs.org/#View-constructor)

*There are several special options that, if passed, will be attached directly to the view: model, collection, el, id, className, tagName, attributes and events.*

What does that mean? Well, the options parameter actually gets used in two ways in the view constructor.

First, it sets the *special options* using this call

```
_.extend(this, _.pick(options, viewOptions));
```

which returns a new object that contain only the special options in `viewOptions`, and then adds those options to the view object.

Next, once these special options have been added, it then calls the initialize function.

```
this.initialize.apply(this, arguments);
```

In this case, it's equivalent to calling

```
currentViewObject.initialize({anOptionsAttribute: 'hello'});
```

Which allows you to access the options object either as a parameter, or through the `arguments` object. As you can see, at no point is the options parameter set as a property, hence calling `this.options` is just nonsensical.

Answer (score 1):

```
View = Backbone.View.extend({
  initialize: function(options){
    console.log(options);
    console.log(options.isSortable);
  }
});

var view = new View({isSortable: true, parent: this });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sbjaz/2/

I don't see why it's not working. Have you double checked your spelling?

"this.options" was removed in backbone 1.1.0 
see:

http://backbonejs.org/#upgrading

> In 1.1, Backbone Views no longer have the options argument attached as this.options automatically. Feel free to continue attaching it if you like.

Comment: i post a fiddle such as recommend Colin (using this.options) and dont work for me.

Comment: I think you are using an old version of backbonejs. I tried the same fiddle with the backbone 1.0 and it works perfectly fine.

Comment: wait, I was wrong. this.options only existed in older versions of backbone, and you were using the latest version, which does not have this.options by default. I updated my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sbjaz/2/